# Minimum sets to cover all sub arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am explaining this question with little modification so that it becomea easy for me to explain.

There are *n* employees and I need to arrange an outing for them on such a day of a month on which all (or max) employees would be available for outing.

Each employee is asked to fill up an online survey stating his availability e.g. 1-31  or 15-17 etc. etc. And some might not be available for even a single day too.
There are no restrictions on the number of trips I have to arrange to cover all employees (not considering who arent available the whole month), but i want to find out minimum set of dates so as to cover all the employees. So in worst case scenario I will have to arrange trip 31 times.

Question: what is the best data structure I can use to run the best fitting algorithm on this data structure? What is the best possible way to solve this problem?

By best of course I mean time and space efficient way but I am also looking for other options to solve it.

The way I think is to maintain an array for 31 ints and initialize it to 0. Run over each employee and based on their available dates increment the array index. At the end sort the array of 31. The maximum value represents the date on qhich max employees are available. And apply the same logic on the left out employees. But the problem is to remove the left out employees. For which I will have to run over whole list of employees once to know which employees can be removed and form a new list of left out employees on which I can apply the previous logic. Running over the list twice this way to remove the employees isnt the best according to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you should exclude employees with no available dates.

Then you problem becomes a variant of [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Your universe `U` is all employees, and collections of sets `S` are days. For each day `i`, you have employee `j` is in set `S[i]` iff that employee is available on day `i`.

That problem is NP-hard. So, unless you want an approximate solution, you must check every `31^2` combination  of days, probably with some pruning.

Answer (score 0):

Select an array from 1 to 31(each index is representing dates of a month).for each date you have to create a linked list(doubly) contains the emp_id who are available on that days(you can simultaneously create this list which will be sorted based on emp_id,and you can keep the information about the size of the list and the index of array which maximum employees).
The largest list must be in the solution(take it as first date).
Now compare each list with the largest list and remove those employees from the list which are already present in the selected largest list.
now do the same procedure and find the second date and so on...
this whole procedure will run in O(n^2)(because 31 is a constant value).
and space will be O(n).

Comment: One of the counterexamples would be: 10 employees; on day one employees 1-8 are available, on day two - employees with even numbers, on day three - employees with odd numbers. Largest list is 1-8 on day one, but minimum coverage is {second day, third day}.